# ¿Cómo listar todos los pagos de un cliente en un ListView según el ID del cliente?

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, webservice

amigos. ¿Saben cómo puedo realizar una lista en un **ListView** según un cliente seleccionado?

Se da click en el detalle de un cliente para que me muestre todos los pagos de ese mismo cliente. En este caso, cuando yo selecciono cualquier cliente, me muestra todos los pagos de los clientes; cosa que está mal. Solo quiero que me liste los pagos del cliente que seleccioné.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class DetallePrestamo extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private TextView iddetalle;
    private TextView totalpago;
    private ListView listView;
    private String JSON_STRING;
    private int totales;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_prestamo);

        String id = "";
        Bundle exttras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (exttras != null) {
            id = exttras.getString("id");
        }
        TextView txtid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detallidpasa);
        txtid.setText(id);

        iddetalle=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.detallid);
        totalpago=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.totaldetades);
        //otro
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisview);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getJSON();
    }

    private void mostrar_cliente() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfiActivities.TAGI_JSON_ARRAY);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String  idprestamo = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID);
                //String nombre = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID_NOMBRE);
                String fechapago = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA);
                String total = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL);



                totales += jo.getInt(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL);
                totalpago.setText(String.valueOf(totales));

                HashMap<String, String> contactos = new HashMap<>();
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID,  idprestamo);
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA, fechapago);
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL, total);

                list.add(contactos);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DetallePrestamo.this, list, R.layout.items_listardetalle,
            new String[]{ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID,ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA,ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL},
            new int[]{R.id.detallid,R.id.fechadetall,R.id.totaldetal});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
    private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(DetallePrestamo.this, "Cargando datos", "Espere...", false, false);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            mostrar_cliente();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(ConfiActivities.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //String empId = map.get(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID).toString();
        //intent.putExtra(ConfiActivities.EMP_ID, empId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo tu código apenas se crea el Activity llamar a la función `getJSON` esta haciendo una petición a una url `ConfiActivities.URL_GET_ALL` creo que ahí es donde esta el error

Cuando ejecutas la función `mostrar_cliente` directamente estas sacando la información que había traído la petición `getJSON`, pero esa petición se mando a traer información antes de que supieras a que cliente quieres ver el detalle... por eso se ve la información de todos, tienes 2 opciones

1. cambias de lugar la ejecución de la función `getJSON` y la mandas a llamar en la función `mostrar_cliente` y mandas como parámetro el ID del cliente para que la petición solo traiga los resultados de ese cliente
2. filtras los resultados de todos los clientes al que te interesa